# Are attributes of tags related to CSS at all?

Tags: html, css, tags, attributes

A colleague and I got into a bit of a debate. Let's say for example that we have an ordered list with the attribute `type="a"`:

```
<ol type="a">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ol>
```

The presence of the attribute changes the style of the list from a numerically numbered list to an alphabetically numbered list. My colleague wanted to know whether this constitutes as CSS.

I argued that it obviously does not, because `type="a"` is an attribute of a tag, while CSS is a style sheet language.

However, my colleague argues that as long as adding or changing an attribute changes the way the element looks, it should be constituted as adding or changing CSS.

They also argued that the `width` and `height` attribute in

```
<img src="..." width="100" height="100">
```

should constitute as CSS as well.

They expanded on their arguement by explaining that for each element, the web browser has it's own stylesheet e.g.

```
ol {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: decimal;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Adding a `type="a"` effectively adds a `ol { list-style-type: lower-alpha; }` to the web browser's style sheet. So since adding the attribute alters the CSS of the web browser, the attribute should constitute as CSS as well.

However, this argument still doesn't really make sense to me, but I can't think of any way to explain why this is wrong.

So my question is: Who is correct? Are CSS and attributes entirely different concepts? Or is my colleague correct in that attributes such as `type="a"` should constitute as CSS (and why)?

Comment: Oh yes I agree with you, form elements is a better example, `<input type="button">` and `<input type="text">` they are very very different in style. In the CSS you'll see something like `input[type="text"]{...}` etc.

Comment: `href` has no direct impact on the css.

Comment: I'm confused by the part of who's right who's wrong, but even a complex webpage is just plain text no formatting at all without CSS (including browser default stylesheet), again form elements are different not sure how they get rendered, it also depends on the browser and OS. HTML/CSS has to be working together all the time. (I guess I'll remove comments after reading, not sure if it's helping at all)

Comment: @Pangloss I reworded that last part. I understand that CSS and HTML has to be working together to make a page appear as more than plain text. But what I am wondering is whether adding an attribute such as `type="a"` to an `<ol>` constitutes as adding or changing the CSS of the page.

Comment: @DanielA.White They agree that `href` does not constitute as CSS. But they insist that something like `type="a"` or  `width="100"` should be counted as CSS because it changes the "styling" of the element.

Comment: I think so @Zsw for the `type="a"` part also read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol#Attributes). Not sure about the `<img>` tag, it's similar to some form tags, as they are called [replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)  i.e. an image has intrinsic dimensions.

Comment: @DanielA.White well, the url in `href` has some impact to CSS too, if it's a visited url, then it applies `a:visited` style, just saying, maybe not related to the question itself. But I like your answer, great source on the Webkit one too.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to render your markup without using CSS at all. Indeed the early browsers did just that. So how can they, per se, constitute CSS? Furthermore, the data contained within the markup can be interpreted without any rendering at all.

Comment: @Alohci That is a good counter-example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real thing that exists for rendering and modifying is the DOM which isn't HTML or CSS. It is a computed representation of HTML, CSS, JavaScript and browser provided defaults.

When you set an attribute, the DOM is modified to modify its style representations. WebKit makes it really easy to see and understandstand this.

When using the attribute - this is what is done in WebKit:

```
void HTMLOListElement::collectStyleForPresentationAttribute(const QualifiedName& name, const AtomicString& value, MutableStyleProperties& style)
{
    if (name == typeAttr) {
        if (value == "a")
            addPropertyToPresentationAttributeStyle(style, CSSPropertyListStyleType, CSSValueLowerAlpha);
        else if (value == "A")
            addPropertyToPresentationAttributeStyle(style, CSSPropertyListStyleType, CSSValueUpperAlpha);
        else if (value == "i")
            addPropertyToPresentationAttributeStyle(style, CSSPropertyListStyleType, CSSValueLowerRoman);
        else if (value == "I")
            addPropertyToPresentationAttributeStyle(style, CSSPropertyListStyleType, CSSValueUpperRoman);
        else if (value == "1")
            addPropertyToPresentationAttributeStyle(style, CSSPropertyListStyleType, CSSValueDecimal);
    } else
        HTMLElement::collectStyleForPresentationAttribute(name, value, style);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/d055853e59dd6cc4cfd835b143e79258bb13c552/Source/WebCore/html/HTMLOListElement.cpp

Comment: You said that setting an attribute isn't CSS, but the webkit source code seems to add `CSSValueLowerAlpha` to `CSSPropertyListStyleType`. So does that mean that adding a style is not equivalent to adding CSS, thus my colleague is incorrect?

Comment: it is setting a style. CSS is one way to set a style. another would be via JavaScript.